# .htaccess file acting weird

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am creating a CMS and having trouble with my .htaccess file, the line following

`RewriteRule ^([-a-z]+)*/([-a-z_]+)*/$ ./page.php?page=$1&order=$2`

will not work no matter what...

What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Here is my full code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks   
RewriteEngine On   

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f   

RewriteRule ^([-a-z]+)*/$ ./page.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([-a-z]+)*/([-a-z_]+)*/$ ./page.php?page=$1&order=$2
RewriteRule ^blog-entry/([-a-z-0-9]+)*/$ ./single.php?post=$1&page=blog
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)*/$ ./page.php?page=blog&num=$1
```

Comment: Any reason for `([-a-z]+)*` instead of `[-a-z]*`?

Comment: No, I'm not very good and thats how I was taught

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put those last 2 rules first, as they are more specific, and the prior 2 rules will match before the latter ones.